# Undefined variable in codeigniter vol.2

Tags: database, view, model, foreach, controller

So, I have already asked for this problem today. But it has reiterate. So, the error is:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: views/main_text_view.php

Line Number: 5

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/main_text_view.php

Line Number: 5

Controller:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

   class First extends CI_Controller
   {

    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('materials_model');
    }    


    public function index()
      {
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('menu_view');
        $this->load->view('about_me_view');
        $this->load->view('navigation_view');
        $this->load->view('search_view');
        $this->load->view('main_text_view',$news);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');

      }


    public function mat()
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['news'] = $this->load->model('materials_model');

    }


   }

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Materials_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function get()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('materials');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}

?>
```

View:

```
<div id="main">
            <div class="post"> <a name="TemplateInfo"></a>
              <h1>Template Info</h1>
              <?php foreach ($news as $one):?>
              <p>Posted by <?=$one['author']?></p>
              <?php endforeach; ?>


<p><strong>Enlighten 1.0</strong> is a free, W3C-compliant, CSS-based website template by <strong><a href="http://www.styleshout.com/">styleshout.com</a></strong>. This work is distributed under the <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/"> Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License</a>, which means that you are free to use and modify it for any purpose. All I ask is that you include a link back to <a href="http://www.styleshout.com/">my website</a> in your credits.</p>
          <p>For more free designs, you can visit <a href="http://www.styleshout.com/">my website</a> to see my other works.</p>
          <p>Good luck and I hope you find my free templates useful!</p>
          <p class="post-footer align-right"> <a href="http://web-mastery.info/" class="readmore">Read more</a> <a href="http://web-mastery.info/" class="comments">Comments (7)</a> <span class="date">Jan 09, 2007</span> </p>
        </div>

            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: It's really obvious. You don't have results from DB and that's why in your template variable $news is null. You should check it using isset().

Comment: Maybe, I can do it. But what it should provides? What I should make, if variable is null?

Comment: You should make a check in your template:
`<?php if(!empty($news)):?>
<?php foreach ($news as $one):?>
              <p>Posted by <?=$one['author']?></p>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>`

Comment: without any changes...A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: controllers/First.php

Line Number: 21

Comment: sorry) here it is:
`<?php if(isset($news) && !empty($news)):?>`

Comment: also this line will cause a warning anyway:
`$this->load->view('main_text_view',$news);`
and this line will not work as expected:
`$data['news'] = $this->load->model('materials_model');`
You can try to do it like this:
`return $data['news'] = $this->materials_model->get();`
and
`$news = $this->mat();
$this->load->view('main_text_view',$news);`

Comment: What of this shall be in controller, model, and view?

Comment: put this
`return $data['news'] = $this->materials_model->get();`
instead of this:
`$data['news'] = $this->load->model('materials_model');`
and this:
`$news = $this->mat(); $this->load->view('main_text_view',$news);`
instead of this:
`$this->load->view('main_text_view',$news);`
in Controller file